# How to change the font of some characters in a section title?

Tags: fonts, sectioning, xetex, luatex, fontspec

I would like to change one or two characters in a section title.  I tried the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{book}
%PACKAGES
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\newfontfamily\myfont{Hiragino Sans W2}[Scale = MatchLowercase, WordSpace = -.3]
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries\centering\large}{}{0pt}{} 
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\normalfont\itshape\centering}{}{0pt}{}

\section{\begin{myfont}~†~\end{myfont}1: First Title}

\end{document}
```

It works in the body, but not in the section.  Perhaps a conflict with titlesec?  I'm using LuaLatex.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `\begin{myfont}`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{book}
%PACKAGES
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\newfontfamily\myfont{Hiragino Sans W2}[Scale = MatchLowercase, WordSpace = -.3]
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries\centering\large}{}{0pt}{} 
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\normalfont\itshape\centering}{}{0pt}{}

\section{{\myfont~†~}1: First Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A possible better coding.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{book}

%PACKAGES
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}

\newfontfamily\myfont{Hiragino Sans W2}[
  Scale = MatchLowercase,
  WordSpace = -.3,
  SlantedFont=*,
  ItalicFont=*,
]
\NewDocumentCommand{\hsym}{m}{{\myfont~#1~}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont\bfseries\centering\large}{}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\normalfont\itshape\centering}{}{0pt}{}

\begin{document}

\section{\hsym{†}1: First Title}

\end{document}
```

The new options to the font loading are to avoid annoying warnings about missing slanted and italic fonts. The `\hsym` macro is better than specifying `\myfont` and `~` each time.

On the other hand, I'm not sure about `WordSpace=-0.3` and the `~` in the definitions. Without them I get

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you very much.